# awk compare 2 files, print match and nonmatch lines

Tags: unix, awk

In this example, need to compare two files f1.txt and f2.txt and obtain matches, and non-matches, for this case I am looking to match 2nd field of second file and 1st field of first file. And print first the second field of f2.txt, then print the entire line of f1.txt. And for no match found on f2.txt to state "Not Found" and then print f1.txt entire line.

**F1.txt**

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8 
1a;2;3;4;5;6;7;8 
1b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8 
2b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
```

**F2.txt**

```
First;1 
Firsta;1a 
Firstb;1b
```

Desired Output:

```
First;1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Firsta;1a;1a;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Firstb;1b;1b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Not Found;Not Found;2b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
```

---

Tried but not working:

```
awk -F";" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;b[$1]=$0;next}{ if (a[$2]=b[$1]) print a[$1],$0;else print "NotAvailable","NotAvailable", $0;}' OFS=";" f2.txt f1.txt
```

Comment: Googled for any similar questions?  You should find about 100,000 on StackOverflow alone.

Comment: tried this command , but it is not working ,awk -F";" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;b[$1]=$0;next}{ if (a[$2]=b[$1]) print a[$1],$0;else print "NotAvailable","NotAvailable", $0;}' OFS=";" f2.txt f1.txt

Comment: while run this command in Cygwin, i got the wrong output$ awk -F ";" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next}{print (a[$1]?a[$1]:"Not Found;Not Found") ";" $0}' f2.txt f1.txt
Not Found;Not Found;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Not Found;Not Found;1a;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Firstb;1b;1b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Not Found;Not Found;2b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8

Comment: @user3214143 Check for spaces in the files. If they are at the end of the line, they will break it. Also if you created the files under windows, run `dos2unix` to correct the line breaks

Comment: thanks for the inputs, did dos2unix ,still not getting the correct output    NotAvailable;NotAvailable;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
NotAvailable;NotAvailable;1a;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
NotAvailable;NotAvailable;1b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
NotAvailable;NotAvailable;2b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Here is the correct script:

```
$ awk -F ";" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next}{print (a[$1]?a[$1]:"Not Found;Not Found") ";" $0}' F2.txt F1.txt 
First;1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Firsta;1a;1a;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Firstb;1b;1b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Not Found;Not Found;2b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
```

Take care to remove any trailing spaces from the input file.

Comment: Hi , what will be the command if i need to compare 3rd column of f1.txt and Second column of f2.txt                      2;3;1;4;5;6;7;8
2;3;1a;4;5;6;7;8
2;3;1b;4;5;6;7;8
2;3;2b;4;5;6;7;8

Comment: Then instead of `a[$1]` you should use `a[$3]`